# linux svn launches meld

Tags: svn, virtual-machine, meld

I'm using a shared VM, its running Fedora 20 Heisenbug.  SVN is version 1.8.3

At some point **meld** was installed and now when running svn diff on the command line **meld** is automatically launched, **meld** is very useful, however there are times when you just want to get the differences without **meld**.

Is there anyway to launch **svn diff** without meld or if not how do I fix it so **meld** isn't launched ?

Comment: By default, `meld` does not cling to `svn`. Finding out where those two applications are combined is key to solving it. Is there an `alias` or a shell function defined for `svn`? Does `command svn diff` launch `meld`?

Comment: Check if you have external diff tool configured in your SVN client: https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, edit the svn configuration using:

```
gedit ~/.subversion/config
```

Search for:

```
diff-cmd =
```

Comment out.